# Existential type as return value

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Consider the following data structure, representing a tree with levels which increase but are not necessarily consecutive:

```
data MyTree (n :: T) where
    MyLeaf :: MyTree n
    MyNode :: Plus n m z => [MyTree ('Succ z)] -> MyTree n
```

where `T` represents the Peano numbers at the type level, defined as

```
class Plus (n :: T) (m :: T) (r :: T) | r n -> m
instance Plus 'Zero m m
instance Plus n m r => Plus ('Succ n) m ('Succ r)
```

It is pretty easy to construct trees like

```
myTreeOne :: MyTree ('Succ 'Zero)
myTreeOne = MyNode ([ MyLeaf ] :: [MyTree ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero))])

myTree :: MyTree 'Zero
myTree = MyNode [ MyLeaf, myTreeOne ]
```

or

```
myLeafTwo :: MyTree ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero))
myLeafTwo = MyLeaf

myOtherTree :: MyTree 'Zero
myOtherTree = MyNode [ myLeafTwo ]
```

Now I would like to define the following function:

```
myTreeComponents MyLeaf              = []
myTreeComponents (MyNode components) = components
```

which just extracts the list of immediate subnodes of the tree, but I'm not able to write it's correct type.

This is the error I get

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘p’                                                                                │
                  with actual type ‘[MyTree ('Succ z)]’                                                               │
        because type variable ‘z’ would escape its scope                                                              │
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by                                                                  │
        a pattern with constructor:                                                                                   │
          MyNode :: forall (n :: T) (m :: T) (z :: T).                                                                │
                    Plus n m z =>                                                                                     │
                    [MyTree ('Succ z)] -> MyTree n,                                                                   │
        in an equation for ‘myTreeComponents’                                                                         │
        at src/Model.hs:159:19-35                                                                                     │
    • In the expression: components                                                                                   │
      In an equation for ‘myTreeComponents’:                                                                          │
          myTreeComponents (MyNode components) = components                                                           │
    • Relevant bindings include                                                                                       │
        components :: [MyTree ('Succ z)] (bound at src/Model.hs:159:26)                                               │
        myTreeComponents :: MyTree n -> p (bound at src/Model.hs:158:1)                                               │
    |                                                                                                                 │
159 | myTreeComponents (MyNode components) = components                                                               │
    |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

With dependent type languages it should be something like

```
exists m. Plus n m z => MyTree n -> [ MyTree ('Succ z) ]
```

Is it possible to write such a type in Haskell? Otherwise how should I write my function?

Comment: You need to define your own existential type using a custom `data` GADT. It will look as `MyTree` but only with the second constructor. It is very tricky, though, to extract `m,z` from the first type to use in the existential: probably, it would be easier if you can add a proxy to `MyNode` constructor. (This is quite painful. If Haskell had real dependent types, or better ambiguous types, it would be easier.)

Comment: thanks @chi, I'm sorry but I find it hard to follow what you are suggesting. Could you please elaborate a more detailed answer?

Comment: Before I wrote my comment, I spent some time trying a solution but it took longer than I expected, and I stopped half way.

Comment: @chi, adding a proxy shouldn't really be too bad. If it's marked strict, it will "unpack" to nothing. There's a GHC proposal to get a better story for binding existential type variables.

Comment: @dfeuer `Plus` is a class defined as `class Plus (n :: T) (m :: T) (r :: T) | r n -> m` with two instances `instance Plus 'Zero m m` and `instance Plus n m r => Plus ('Succ n) m ('Succ r)`

Comment: @dfeuer That's good news. I recently was disappointed to notice that ambiguous types are [not handled as I expected](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15119), so I'm hoping that in the future we can completely get rid of proxies and use only type variables everywhere.

Comment: @chi, see [the proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/96). I'm personally a bit concerned about what the ordering of all those type variables does to library APIs that aren't designed around those features.

Answer (score 8):

This is an adaptation of your code with a `Proxy` added, so to "remember" the number `m`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, 
    MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies,
    FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

import Data.Proxy

data T = Zero | Succ T

class Plus (n :: T) (m :: T) (z :: T) | n m -> z where

instance Plus n 'Zero n
instance Plus n m z => Plus n ('Succ m) ('Succ z)

data MyTree (n :: T) where
    MyLeaf :: MyTree n
    MyNode :: Plus n m z => ! (Proxy m) -> [MyTree ('Succ z)] -> MyTree n

myTreeOne :: MyTree ('Succ 'Zero)
myTreeOne = MyNode (Proxy :: Proxy 'Zero) ([ MyLeaf ] :: [MyTree ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero))])

myTree :: MyTree 'Zero
myTree = MyNode (Proxy :: Proxy 'Zero) [ MyLeaf, myTreeOne ]

myLeafTwo :: MyTree ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero))
myLeafTwo = MyLeaf

myOtherTree :: MyTree 'Zero
myOtherTree = MyNode (Proxy :: Proxy ('Succ 'Zero)) [ myLeafTwo ]
```

To be able to write the final function `myTreeComponents`, we need a custom existential type:

```
data Nodes (n :: T) where
    Nodes :: Plus n m z => ! (Proxy m) -> [MyTree ('Succ z)] -> Nodes n
```

This is essentially `MyTree` with only the second constructor.
Finally, pattern matching now suffices.

```
myTreeComponents :: MyTree n -> Nodes n
myTreeComponents MyLeaf                = Nodes (Proxy :: Proxy 'Zero) []
myTreeComponents (MyNode p components) = Nodes p components
```

Comment: Nice! I tried to eliminate the proxies (and have an answer to that effect); while doing so, I noticed there's quite a few subtle tricks happening in this answer. Very nice to see a worked example.

Answer (score 4):

You can usually use CPS to encode existentials.

```
exists a. f a
```

can be represented as

```
(forall a. f a -> r) -> r
```

However, I don't think your

```
exists m. Plus n m z => MyTree n -> [ MyTree ('Succ z) ]
```

is the type you want.  First, the exists is in the wrong place -- there does not exist a single global type `m`, but rather for each `MyTree n` there is a possibly distinct such `m`.

```
MyTree n -> exists m. Plus n m z => [ MyTree ('Succ z) ]
```

Here the caller gets to choose `z`, and, given evidence that `n + m = z`, can extract the list of children.  That is consistent, but such evidence might be hard to come by. I think you actually want a double existential:

```
MyTree n -> exists m z. Plus n m z & [ MyTree ('Succ z) ]
```

and I'm using `&` as the dual to `=>`, a type which comes packed with a dictionary rather than requiring it as an argument.

```
type a & b = (Dict a, b)
```

So this says, for any tree at level `n`, there is some `z >= n` (witnessed by addition with `m`) such that there is a list of children at level `'Succ z`.  Yes, I think that's right.  So now let's CPS encode it to:

```
MyTree n -> (forall m z. Plus n m z => [ MyTree ('Succ z) ] -> r) -> r
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? I don't think it can work without proxies. Even with ambiguous types on, I failed. With proxies it should work, I believe.

Comment: @chi I tried to compile my function with the signature proposed in the last line and everything seems fine

Answer (score 4):

I like chi's fix, because using `Proxy`s to store types is a nice trick to have under your belt. In his answer, the `Proxy` is used to disambiguate what `m` to use in the `Plus n m z` constraint when calling the `Nodes` constructor. (There's a `Plus n m z` constraint in scope at that point, but without the proxy, there's no way to tell the compiler to choose it.)

Besides `Proxy`, there's another way to fix ambiguous types: eliminate the ambiguous type. In this case, that's `m`. So, instead of a `Plus n m z` class, we'll have a `LE n z` class that has all the same instances but doesn't mention `m` anywhere. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, TypeFamilies, 
    MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies,
    FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

data T = Zero | Succ T

class LE (n :: T) (z :: T)
instance LE 'Zero n
instance LE n z => LE ('Succ n) ('Succ z)
```

There's one wrinkle. In chi's answer, he uses a slightly modified definition of `Plus` that gives a `Plus n 'Zero n` instance for free, but in your formulation that's not available, and consequently `LE n n` does not come for free. So we'll have to decorate our leaves a little bit.

```
data MyTree (n :: T) where
    MyLeaf :: LE n n => MyTree n
    MyNode :: LE n z => [MyTree ('Succ z)] -> MyTree n
```

All the concrete trees are just as they were before (no extra `Proxy` needed).

```
myTreeOne :: MyTree ('Succ 'Zero)
myTreeOne = MyNode [ MyLeaf :: MyTree ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero)) ]

myTree :: MyTree 'Zero
myTree = MyNode [ MyLeaf, myTreeOne ]

myLeafTwo :: MyTree ('Succ ('Succ 'Zero))
myLeafTwo = MyLeaf

myOtherTree :: MyTree 'Zero
myOtherTree = MyNode [ myLeafTwo ]
```

And the only difference in `myTreeComponents` compared to chi's answer (besides erasing the `Proxy`) is that we need to bring a type variable into scope for use in the body.

```
data Nodes (n :: T) where
    Nodes :: LE n z => [MyTree ('Succ z)] -> Nodes n

myTreeComponents :: forall n. MyTree n -> Nodes n
myTreeComponents MyLeaf              = Nodes ([] :: [MyTree ('Succ n)])
myTreeComponents (MyNode components) = Nodes components
```

Answer (score -1):

something like (I don't know if such type allowed, and cannot check it now)

```
MyNode n -> forall z .Plus n m z => [MyTree ('Succ z)]
```

`z` type is not exposed so it is allowed to be any. If `z`'s type were exposed by `myTreeComponents`, the caller could specify a concrete type for it, which it must not be able to do

Comment: thanks, but it does not seem to work. The error message is the same

Comment: This uses universal instead of existential quantification, so it can not work.